# RLMObject with Array of NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, arrays, realm

I've been upgrading a project to use Realm as the persistence store and I'm not able to find any documentation on how to use an array of strings in one of my models.

The implementation of an Array for a RLMObject is to use an RLMArray where T inherits RLMObject

I could make an object that inherits.. property inside which is string... but that seems like quite some overhead to replace an NSArray of strings.

Does anyone know the recommended best practice to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Realm Cocoa 3.0 you can simply do `RLMArray<RLMString> *array;` and no longer need the wrapper object type.

---

In older versions of Realm you need an RLMObject which contains the string:

```
@interface StringObject : RLMObject
@property NSString *value;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(StringObject)

@implementation StringObject
@end

@interface Object : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<StringObject> *array;
@end
```

Comment: Am I the only one with this error? `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key value.`

Comment: @Thomas Goyne, Converting StringObject back to NSSString (i.e. stringObj.value) gives error. Any idea ?

Comment: didnt work for me, StringObject and NSString does work