# Store array in Realm object

Tags: ios, swift, orm, realm

I'm new to Realm in Swift. Is there any way to store an array of strings in Realm Object?

I have a JSON Object like:

```
"firstName": "John",
"imgName": "e9a07f7d919299c8fe89a30022151135cd63773f.jpg",
"lastName": "Wood",
"permissions": {
    "messages": ["test", "check", "available"]
},
```

How can I store *messages* array in *permissions* key?

Answer (score 12):

You could something like:

```
class Messages: Object {
    dynamic var message = ""
}

class Permission: Object {
    let messages = List<Messages>()
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var firstName = ""
    dynamic var imgName = ""
    dynamic var lastName = ""
    var permissions : Permission = Permission()
}
```

Anyways, I think now is well documented in [Realm Swift Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one simple technique that doesn't require `List<T>` if you're sure your strings can be safely tokenized.

```
class Person: Object {
    private let SEPARATOR = "||"

    dynamic var permissionsString: String? = nil
    var permissions: [String] {
        get {
            guard let perms = self.permissionsString else { return [] }
            return perms.componentsSeparatedByString(SEPARATOR)
        }
        set {
            permissionsString = newValue.count > 0 ? newValue.joinWithSeparator(SEPARATOR) : nil
        }
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["permissions"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

This question already answered by someone , Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182699/rlmobject-with-array-of-nsstrings)

You do currently need an RLMObject which contains the string:

```
@interface StringObject : RLMObject
@property NSString *value;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(StringObject)

@implementation StringObject
@end

@interface Object : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<StringObject> *array;
@end
```