# Store string type array in RealM objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, realm

i want to store string type of array in **Realm objective c**.

Ex array :- 
**["58575bc922e87bd14480132f","58575c5c22e87bd144801331","58575cc922e87bd144801333","58575d5b22e87bd144801335","58575bc922e87bd14480132f","58575c5c22e87bd144801331","58575cc922e87bd144801333","58575d5b22e87bd144801335","58575bc922e87bd14480132f","58575c5c22e87bd144801331","58575cc922e87bd144801333","58575d5b22e87bd144801335"]**

Comment: Please show what ou have tried!

Comment: I am not able to get any idea to how to create object class for this type of array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inherit from RLMObject class and put the NSString into your RLMObject as a property.
Then you can make new RLMObject one more time, with a RLMArray of previously made RLMObject now.

```
@interface StringObject: RLMObject
@property NSString *stringValue;
@end

@interface RealmObject: RLMObject
@property RLMArray<StringObject> *realmArray
@end
```

After this manipulation feel free to use it. F.e. use fast enumeration loop to put the strings into realm RLMArray.

```
NSArray *arrayOfStrings = @[@"58575bc922e87bd14480132f",@"58575c5c22e87bd144801331",@"58575cc922e87bd144801333",@"58575d5b22e87bd144801335",@"58575bc922e87bd14480132f",@"58575c5c22e87bd144801331",@"58575cc922e87bd144801333",@"58575d5b22e87bd144801335",@"58575bc922e87bd14480132f",@"58575c5c22e87bd144801331",@"58575cc922e87bd144801333",@"58575d5b22e87bd144801335"];

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

RealmObject *realmObject = [RealmObject new];
for (NSString *value in arrayOfStrings) {
    StringObject *string = [StringObject new];
    string.stringValue = value;

    [realmObject.realmArray addObject:string];
}

[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addObject:realmObject];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Thanks to [RLMObject with Array of NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182699/rlmobject-with-array-of-nsstrings) 
And 
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3415

Comment: not working, the StringObject value always contain : "key" -> "value", i dont know why this  commend were marked is right answer.

Comment: Well, its been a long time, i will check this out one more time a little bit later and respond you back.

Comment: Hello, i found the similar question, still reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724595/storing-an-array-of-strings-using-realms-rlmarray

Comment: Thanks, i will check. Just a little bit busy right now.