# How to store list of primitives (NSString) on Realm database

Tags: objective-c, realm

I'm trying to take advantage of a feature introduced in Realm Cocoa 3.0: Store a list of primitives. Previous to that version the only way to do it was creating a new subclass of `RLMObject` containing a property like `@property NSString *stringValue` and then creating an `RLMArray` property on the model intended to use an array of strings, integers or any other primitive. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665739/store-string-type-array-in-realm-objective-c) for more information.

According to the [Realm Cocoa 3.0 announcement](https://realm.io/blog/realm-cocoa-reaches-3-0/) we have now support for **Arrays of primitives**, which in an example using Swift shows that it is possible to create a database model as

```
class Student : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let testScores = List<Int>()
}
```

So, how do I create a property like this one using Objective-C? I've been trying to do something like the following code:

```
@interface Game : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property RLMArray<NSString *> *tags;  // First attempt
// @property NSArray<NSString> *tags;  // Second attempt
@end
```

My attempts are, until now, unsuccessful as I am getting an error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'tags' requires a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray<Person>.'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Realm's documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#many-to-many):

> `RLMArray`s can store primitive values in lieu of Realm objects. In order to do so, constrain a `RLMArray` with one of the following protocols: `RLMBool`, `RLMInt`, `RLMFloat`, `RLMDouble`, `RLMString`, `RLMData`, or `RLMDate`.

Your declaration would be:

```
@property RLMArray<RLMString> *tags;
```

Or, if you want to also make use of Objective-C generics:

```
@property RLMArray<NSString *><RLMString> *tags;
```

Comment: is of type 'RLMArray<RLMString>' which is not a supported RLMArray object type. RLMArrays can only contain instances of RLMObject subclasses. See https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#to-many for more information.'

Comment: The documentation was changed and does not mention primitives (maybe due to Swift transition), but for ObjC it WORKS.